# Divide each element of a list of 500 matrices by another matrix

Tags: matrix, vector

Lets say that I have a Table of dimension (3,3,500) and I'd like to perform element-wise division by a 3x3 matrix along the third dimension (of length 500 in this case).

What is the most elegant way of vectorizing this operation?

Comment: why not simply use `Divide`; e.g. `mata = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3, 500}]; matb =  ArrayReshape[CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;; 9]], {3, 3}];
mata/matb`?

Comment: This is true!  Sorry, coming from the MATLAB world where no inference is made about what you're doing and matrix dimensions have to match for element-wise operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways, but the most elegant is to use the method in kguler's comment on your original post, which is just to divide:

```
M = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3, 500}];
div = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
result = M / div;
```

Because the Divide (/) function has the Listable attribute, it automatically threads over the outer level of its arguments in the case that they are lists; accordingly, M / div effectively becomes:

```
{M[[1]]/div[[1]], M[[2]]/div[[2]], M[[3]]/div[[3]]}
```

Because each of these are also lists, however, this gets further threaded into:

```
{{M[[1,1]]/div[[1,1]], M[[1,2]]/div[[1,2]], M[[1,3]]/div[[1,3]]},
 {M[[2,1]]/div[[2,1]], M[[2,2]]/div[[2,2]], M[[2,3]]/div[[2,3]]},
 {M[[3,1]]/div[[3,1]], M[[3,2]]/div[[3,2]], M[[3,3]]/div[[3,3]]}}
```

which is precisely what you want. If your array M were instead a 500x3x3 matrix, you could do something like this:

```
M = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {500, 3, 3}];
div = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
(* Use ConstantArray[] *)
result = M / ConstantArray[div, 500];
(* Use Transpose[] *)
result = Transpose[Transpose[M, {3,1,2}] / div, {2,3,1}];
(* Use Map[] *)
result = (#/div)& /@ M;
```

In the latter case, my personal preference is to use ConstantArray[], which, in my own tests, was the fastest as well (they are listed in order of their AbsoluteTimings).

Comment: As kguler commented, why not just use `M/div` ?

Comment: kguler's comment wasn't posted when I started my response; I'm actually surprised that it works. My recollection in prior versions of Mathematica was that mismatched division explicitly failed; e.g., {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} / {1,2,3} would not work. I just tested it in 10.1, however, and it seemed to work. Does anyone know if this has changed or if I'm just misremembering?

Comment: You have misremembered - automatic `Listable` threading works on the outermost dimension. In your example both lists are length 3 so it threads in all *Mathematica* versions.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this is pretty obvious now that I think about it. I've updated my answer to reflect the correction.